# Is there a recognized name for the 'grippy' part of an interface that indicates movability?

Tags: icon

Gmail (for instance) shows this dotted widget next to the email items to hint that you can drag'n'drop them.

[image]

Is there a generally recognized name for this?

Grab bar?
Handle? (this sounds too generic)

Comment: I instantly though t "Handle" but could be wrong...

Comment: Personally, I'd call it `drag-and-drop indicator` or something similar, maybe prefixed with `dotted`. I assume it's to describe it in some kind of documentation, so in my opinion, the safest bet is to be as thorough and unambiguous as possible.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter That might get some upvotes as an answer. Mine certainly.

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter Actually, I was trying to squeeze some usage guidelines for this sort of UX out of google, and couldn't find a decent wording for the query.

Comment: Maybe better to ask on [Ux.se].

Comment: There is an existing question about this on UX: [What do you call embedded dotts/lines which indicate sliding in GUI?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/25692/31917)

Comment: I would call it a grab bar.

Comment: We've always called it a "handle" or "drag handle"

Comment: I call them just "handles". And as you are asking for a generally recognized name, you will just need to collect many many more comments from different users and then see what the general user recognizes.  :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the Microsoft Manual of Style (4th edition), the correct term is "move handle."

> In the user interface of various programs, a handle is an element used to move or size an object. Use *move handle* or *sizing handle*. Do not use *size handle*, *grab handle*, *little box*, or similar phrases.

While "move handle" probably isn't self-evident to the average user by itself, the context should be sufficient, e.g. "Click the move handle next to the message, and then drag it to the Trash icon."

Comment: Microsoft? Standards?

Comment: @Octopus Yeah, I know. Compared to to some of the other style manuals out there for technical writing, the current version of the MS manual is actually very good though. It's gone through a few iterations, and the current version is pretty well thought out.

Answer (score 1):

The grocery shopping app "Out of Milk" calls it a "grippy" when explaining its use to its users.  I found this thread after coming across the term there and searching for it on Google.

That the term seems to have been independently invented both here and there makes it a good candidate for general adoption.

Comment: But the fact you were searching for it kind of eludes to how unintuitive "grippy" may be. :)